# Сериализации JSON останавливается брекпоинтом, после обновления Xcode

Tags: json, swift, xcode, breakpoint

После обновления Xcode до версии 11,6 моя функция проверки валидация json и сериализации json выдаёт исключения если передать не json и останавливается брекпоинтом что мешает мне дебагингу если просто открыть приложения без дебага или удалить брекпоин с проекта то приложения работает норм.

У меня в проекте стоит только **Swift Error breakpoint** .

Ещё я одного не пойму почему код написанный внутри конструкции try сначала останавливается breakpoint - ом потом если пропустить этот брекпоинт потом идет к catch разве оно не должно прости перейти к конструкции catch а не останавливать приложения.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(isValidJSON(jsonString: "test"))
    }

    func isValidJSON(jsonString:String) -> Bool {
        var res = false
        let json = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        do{
            if try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject] != nil{
                res =  true
            }
            else if try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json!, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String: Any]] != nil {
                res =  true
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return res
    }
```

В блоке catch печатается

```
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

Мне бы хотелось как раньше чтобы xcode пропустил эту ошибку.

[image: Вот как это происходит]

Comment: у вас какая версия икскода до этого стояла? у меня на 11.5 такое же поведение

Comment: @schmidt9 раньше у меня было xcode 11.3.1

Comment: это любопытный вопрос, поэтому я его также задал несколько в иной формулировке здесь, взяв ваш пример, в целом идея состоит в том, можно ли добавить исключение для конкретного класса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63284929/how-to-exclude-a-class-with-swift-error-breakpoint